# Values that map to multiple keys in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to combine keys with the same value in a dictionary, for example
 di = {'dog':'A', 'cat':'A'}

to become

{'A':['dog', 'cat']}

I can reverse the dictionary no problem,but cannot seem to code a way to combine keys.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: if you're wanting to make a value have two keys assigned to it you're missing the point of a dictionary. it would make more sense to have the value be the key in the first place if you're trying to do that. alternatively, use a tree where there is a hierarchy if you believe that the values will need values themselves.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is more simple than that, and being brand new to Python, maybe I am not asking clearly.  If I have multiple keys with the same value, what I am trying to do is group them together.  Does that mean that I have to make the keys the values and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have as code, and it has reversed the keys and values, but has dropped any keys with the same values.  Is there a simple way to keep all of the keys and values?

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    for k, v in sorted(dict1.items(), key = lambda (k, v): k):
        dict2[v] = k



return dict2
```

Comment: actually, I see some of my code is redundant.  I took out the first for line.  I still get the same answer from my dictionary, where the keys and values are flipped, but it eliminates one of the key value pairs because they both have the same original value

Comment: Figured it out using a for loop, reversing key and value, and using append.